# Automate tmux session creation on specific python file. (bash ?)

Tags: python, bash, ssh, server, tmux

I am new to all this server side stuff, and I have a server on which I need to start up multiple tmux sessions with the same python script multiple times.

How can I automate this process,( usign bash etc)
This is what I do currently:

```
tmux / cd python /pyhon3 xshares.py / ctrl-b / d / tmux ...
```

Repeatedly, which takes a lot of time, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm creator of 2 open source, python-based `tmux(1)` tools: [libtmux](https://libtmux.git-pull.com) and [tmuxp](https://tmuxp.git-pull.com).

**tmux session managers**

If I had to guess, by "automate" you are looking for a "tmux session manager". Some of those include (non-exhaustively):

- [teamocil](https://github.com/remi/teamocil)
- [tmuxinator](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator)
- [tmuxp](https://tmuxp.git-pull.com) (the one I wrote)

The gist of these tools is there's a declarative [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) configuration encapsulating a tmux session, and its windows and panes.

To get a better idea what this looks like, assume `mysession.yaml`:

```yaml
session_name: my session
windows:
  - window_name: another window
    panes:
    - shell_command:
      - python3 ./myscript.py
    - shell_command: python3 ./myscript2.py
  - window_name: another window
    panes:
    - shell_command:
      - pane
    - pane
```

You could then launch it via command (assuming you have tmuxp installed via `pip install --user tmuxp`):

```sh
tmuxp load ./mysession.yaml
```

This will create and automatically launch you into the tmux session declared in the YAML file. Here are some [examples](https://tmuxp.git-pull.com/configuration/examples.html) for inspiration.

**Scripting tmux**

On the outside chance I misunderstood - e.g. you want to pilot tmux programmatically, you could do this through shell commands to `tmux` itself or libtmux. It could be better to ask a question pivoted toward *manual*, *scripted* control of tmux. I can help with that, too. :)